# popup with JS and innerHTML with parameters

Tags: php, parameters, parameter-passing, innerhtml, popupwindow

I have a JS file , and I used innerHTML to make a link , and I passed 2 parameters.
the code is :

```
innerHTML  = "<a href='http://tamarp.someee.com/test.php?code="+row[cur].name+"&name="+row[cur].real+"'>ADD</a>";
```

Its works fine ,but I want this link to be in a popup window.
what should I add here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the actual link to be in a popup window, or do you want clicking the link to cause a popup window to open?

Comment: @MattBall Seriously? :D Who would want the first one?

Comment: @jadkik94 possibly the OP. The question is unclear, which is why I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Add `target="_blank"`.

`innerHTML  = "<a href='http://tamarp.someee.com/test.php?code="+row[cur].name+"&name="+row[cur].real+"' target='_blank'>ADD</a>";`

Comment: i want it to be a actual link to be in a popup window.
like target="_blank", but i want the window in popup

Comment: Do you mean you want the page at http://..../ to show in a dialog inside the page similar to what @kr0k linked to?

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't think you can decide if the link will open in a new tab or a new window...

Comment: Okay, so as I said, this is it. I don't think you can decide how the popup shows. It can show in a tab or a window, depending on the browser and the configuration...